# Automatic Flow Chart Generator For C/C++ - eclipse plugin

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Is there any flow chart generator plugin for eclipse indigo v3.7, that automatically generates the flow chart for the C/C++ code? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried doxygen ? (www.doxygen.org)

Comment: But i am using Windows. And doxygen is for Mac and Linux.

Comment: Doxygen works perfectly well with Windows.

Comment: @Juhana and Pih Thank you both for helping. I will check and let you guys know if I have any trouble with it.

Comment: @Pih Answer it in answer place so I can accept it. Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen http://www.doxygen.org is very good :)

Comment: Doxygen generates `flow charts` as the OP was looking for?